# Ajax jQuery JSON calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I needing some help here if possible. I have a JSON file and I'm trying to get just 1 result from the image files and specify which image by a number e. g. the first one - is this possible. I have tried lots of different [1] ways but I'm clearly doing something wrong here.

Here's my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/garrycalliopix/Z233A/

```
$(function(){
    $.get('http://sunrise.bluechipholidays.co.uk/webservices/property/images/apikey/demo/propertycode/zinc52/propertycode/proch', function(data){
    var $imagetest = $('#imagetest');
    $(data.data).each(function(i, x){
        $(x.images).each(function(j, k){
            var $img = $('<img></img>');
            $img.attr[1]; //i want the 2nd image returned
            $img.attr('width', '150px');
            $img.attr('height', '75px');
            $img.attr("src", k.url).appendTo("#imagetest");
        });

    });
});
});
```

`[0]` is the image number returned not the count of images: `[2]` would be the 3rd image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are looking to get the second image?
You can get the second image with this small example.

Example below returns two images, are those images the ones you want or do you want only the first?

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z233A/3/)

```
$.get('http://sunrise.bluechipholidays.co.uk/webservices/property/images/apikey/demo/propertycode/zinc52/propertycode/proch', function(data){
        var $imagetest = $('#imagetest');
        var j = 0; // keep a counter to count which element you want to display
        $(data.data).each(function(i, x){ // loop through all elements in data.data
            j++; // add one (j = j + 1)
            if(j == 2){ // choose which one you want to display, 2 is the second iteration of $(data.data).each()
                var $img = $('<img></img>');
                            $img.attr('width', '150px');
                $img.attr('height', '75px');
                $img.attr("src", x.images[2].url).appendTo("#imagetest");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: hi thanks for that. i want just 1 image but want to choose which one

Comment: hi well the code you did i can choose by changing the [number] but how do i return just 1 result?

Comment: I have updated my answer for you. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: hi yeah thats great thanks. are you able to explain how the code is put together? just so i can learn from what you are teaching me - thank you anyway

Comment: I have added some comments  to my code, if some things are still not clear feel free to ask.